# Bad voltage regulator?

Tags: nissan, alternator, altima

1999 nissan altima.  Battery and brake light came , had it tested at o'riley alternator tested bad voltage regulator. Replaced with rebuilt alternator. Cranked car, lights are off everything is good till I crank car again, lights are back on. Went back to o'Riley and rebuilt alternator tested bad 12.4 volt output.  They gave me another alternator but my question is did I just get a bad alternator or is there something frying them? Does anybody have any ideas of what I could check?

Comment: It could of been a bad replacement part, did you reconnect the ground wire to the alternator casing when you reinstalled the part?

Comment: I did replace the ground wire.

Answer (score 4):

There'd be no way to tell for sure if something was frying them, but would suggest to you this would be highly unlikely. **It is completely within reason for the rebuilt alternator to have gone bad** ... that's why they have a warranty. Yes, it's a PITB to take on and off, but at least it didn't cost you anymore than an extra trip to the store.

Comment: I  would ask them to test the 2nd rebuilt unit before you left the store. Years ago it wasn't unheard of for a whole run to fail early. Rebuilders typically did them in batches. So if they got a bad box of bearings or regulators, etc, Every unit of that type was suspect.

Comment: @mikes - I always have them do this with either rebuilt or new ones. Doesn't save you every time, but does some of the time.

Comment: Thanks.  I did get another and had them test it.  Tested good just hoping to prevent frying new one if there is something I could check first.

Comment: It's not too bad to install on this car, better than 93 S10

Comment: I went through (I think) four O'Reilly alternators before I found one that worked on my Nissan - only on the last did I think of getting them to test it first. (I still use O'Reilly. I'll never have another Nissan! :) )

Comment: Put the second alternator on and so far it works good.  Not a nissan fan either its wife's old car and gets better gas millage than my truck so it is a work car.  Thanks for advice.